# Redirecting User to The Destination Page in PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, settings

I am trying to create a guest user for visitors who don't have account on the site. Following code working fine however users are redirected to the home page instead of destination page. My goal is to redirect users to where they are heading to.

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $creds = array();
        $creds['user_login'] = 'test@test.com';
        $creds['user_password'] = '123456';
        $creds['remember'] = true;
        $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
        wp_redirect(home_url());
    }
```

Comment: see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/274572) for a way to get the url of the current page.

Comment: I tried most of the solution from the post you suggested but none of them worked for me. I am giving the link to a page if you  want to experiment: ezcliparts.com/downloads/seamless-geometric-digital-paper-pattern-abstract-hand-drawn-background/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very good thing that I can't experiment with the php code on your site. :D
try this:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        global $wp;
        $this_page = add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url( $wp->request ) );
        $creds = array();
        $creds['user_login'] = 'test@test.com';
        $creds['user_password'] = '123456';
        $creds['remember'] = true;
        $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
        wp_redirect($this_page);
    }
```

Comment: It worked like crazy. Thanks